# What's the regex corresponding to this DFA?

Tags: regular-expressions

Here is a DFA from a research project. We created the DFA manually.
We are interested in which regex is this DFA corresponding to.
Certainly, there could be multiple regex corresponding to it; we prefer a simpler one.

[image]

Inspired by the first answer from Karolis Juodelė, one correct **Answer** should be:

`(00*10*1|1(0*|(10)*)*110*1)*1(0*|(10)*)*110*`

Comment: You forgot to label the loop from $E$ to $E$ - the input 0.

Comment: Since you did not include any of your own thoughts and particular issues, this question is completely covered by the referenced question.

Answer (score 3):

$$(00^*10^*1 ~~~ | ~~~ 10^*(10)^*110^*1)^*~~~10^*(10)^*110^*$$
This should be one representation. Not sure if it could be made simpler. The part from $($ to $|$ represents one lap in the upper cycle. The part from $|$ to $)$ represents a lap in the lower cycle. The last part represents the path from $A$ to $D$.

Comment: The regex as identified by Karolis (00∗10∗1 |10∗(10)∗110∗1)∗ 10∗(10)∗110∗ is of the type ((R1 | R2)1)* R2. Where R1 = 00*10* , R2 = 10*(10)*110\*.

Comment: Your answer is really inspiring, though there is a minor error: `0*(10)*` should be `(0*|(10)*)*` since both `0*` and `(10)*` can go back to node B.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I haven't made a mistake, I get $(0^{+}10^{\ast}1)^{\ast}10^{\ast}(0^{+}1)^{\ast}10^{\ast}$ via one application of the DFA to regular expression conversion algorithm, however there are up to $5!$ possible answers as there are $5$ states to eliminate. I would assume some of these give the same answer of course. The order I happened to choose was $F, D, E, B, C$.